# Why is Safari asking the obvious when I programmatically print page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser, printing, safari, cross-browser

What does this dialog mean? *Of course I want to print a page after pressing a "print" button*, **what's the purpose of it and how do get around it?**

When I hit "print" it doesn't print straight away anyway but just shows the expected dialog with the print preview.

[image]

The code (it's vuejs) is simple. I'm waiting for some asynchronous stuff to finished and then I invoke the print when the promise is resolved:

```
this.$refs.export.prepare().then(() => {
    window.print();
});
```

All the other browsers are just fine with this.

Comment: Oviously Safari has another security about printing.

Comment: Does it do this everytime? I'm just cross broweser testing and couldnt find anything about it, I do not use Safari

Comment: it's probably because the print is initiated by javascript

Comment: What's the point not allowing the user to decide if he want to print and is trusting your js?